# Java return statement priority

Tags: java, tree, return

I have this code:

```
private String buscar(Nodo nodo, Nodo raiz) {
    System.out.println(nivel);
    this.nivel++;

    if (raiz != null) {
        if (nodo.getValor() == raiz.getValor()) {
            System.out.println("es igual");
            return "El número " + nodo.getValor() + " está en el nivel: " + this.nivel;

        } else if (nodo.getValor() < raiz.getValor()) {
            buscar(nodo, raiz.getIzq());

        } else {
            System.out.println("es mayor");
            buscar(nodo, raiz.getDer());

        }
    } else {
        return "El número " + nodo.getValor() + " no forma parte del árbol";
    }

    return null;

}

public String buscar(int valor) {
    this.nivel = 0;
    Nodo nodo = new Nodo(valor);
    return this.buscar(nodo, this.raiz);
}
```

and is always execute the last return sentence (return null), even when the if sentence becomes true. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Is it because you only return from this condition: `nodo.getValor() == raiz.getValor()`? I think you meant change *`buscar(nodo, raiz.getIzq());`* and *`buscar(nodo, raiz.getDer());`* to **`return buscar(nodo, raiz.getIzq());`** and **`return buscar(nodo, raiz.getDer());`**?

Comment: You didn't show the code for `Nodo`, and you need to do some basic debugging, stepping through the code and seeing where it goes wrong.

Comment: @CardinalSystem You were right, i must use a return in all options, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the result of your recursive calls, you can also eliminate two of the `else` conditions (since you `return`). And, I would prefer `String.format` over concatenation. Like,

```
private String buscar(Nodo nodo, Nodo raiz) {
    System.out.println(nivel);
    this.nivel++;

    if (raiz != null) {
        if (nodo.getValor() == raiz.getValor()) {
            System.out.println("es igual");
            return String.format("El número %d está en el nivel: %d", 
                        nodo.getValor(), this.nivel);
        } else if (nodo.getValor() < raiz.getValor()) {
            return buscar(nodo, raiz.getIzq()); // return the recursive result
        }
        System.out.println("es mayor");
        return buscar(nodo, raiz.getDer()); // return the recursive result
    }
    return String.format("El número %d no forma parte del árbol", nodo.getValor());
}
```